# Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin refuses to install on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I've seen many similar posts to what I'm asking, but none seem to actually answer the question relevant to Windows.

My problem is that the ADT Plugin wont install in Eclipse. I am on the newest version of Eclipse so that shouldn't be a problem. The Android SDK and Manager also installed just fine. I am on Windows 7 x64 with x64 Eclipse. The other 3 parts of the Developer Tools including Android DDMS, Hierarchy Viewer, and Traceview install just fine. The error code is as follows:

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what's your version of eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through The seven circles of hell untill i solved this.
What worked for me is that i installed an **Older** version of Eclipse, Helios.

Some methods you can try if you prefer using your existing version:

- Run Eclipse as Administrator
- Follow the [Troubleshooting](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#troubleshooting) in the official site
- In the "Available Software Sites" in preferances of Eclipse make sure the Galileo is checked and all other relavent sites
- Make sure you are running on Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and not Classic (Not sure about this one, but read it somewhere)

Answer (score 5):

You need to go to "Install New Software" and select "Available Software Sites".

There add:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo and http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7.

After that when you try to install ADT Plugin it should work.

This worked for me for Eclipse 3.8 (Indigo) on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I should thank a ton! I am very grateful to you. You made me sleep after a week. But what could be the problem?

Comment: What I am suspecting is that some required component is not present in the ADT Plugin repository which is available in the updates repository. So when you add both these also in the available software sites your eclipse is able to see all the required components so it goes ahead with the install.

Answer (score 0):

You can boil down eric.itzhak answer to his last, single, silver bullet answer:

- "Make sure you are running on Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and not Classic"